# AngularJS Slick script and ID

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

New to AngularJS and looking at http://devmark.github.io/angular-slick-carousel/#/

Can someone explain what is going on below, especially the script and id="tpl.html"

```
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
            <h3>{{ i.label }}</h3>
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl2.html">
            <h3>{{ i }}</h3>
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script
found the answer here,

Load the content of a  element into $templateCache, so that the template can be used by ngInclude, ngView, or directives. The type of the  element must be specified as text/ng-template, and a cache name for the template must be assigned through the element's id, which can then be used as a directive's templateUrl.